# div not centering in compatibility mode

Tags: html, css, compatibility

When IE8 is "normal" standards compliant mode the html and css below does what it should and properly centers the red div. However in compatibility mode it does not get centered. Anyone here able to explain why and suggest an alternative?

```
<html>
   <head><title>test</title></head>
<body>
    <div 
        style="position: absolute;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 900px;
        background-color: red"
    >
        test
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you specifying a doctype? It makes a difference

Comment: What Hawxby said, and also the combination of left: 0; right: 0; and width: 900px; makes little sense.

Comment: currently using this doctype `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/loose.dtd">` I know I should use strict but this is a legacy site done by someone else and changing to strict or even `<!doctype html>` messes everything up and it will be a real pita to have to redo every page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to make it working without the doctype just do this way:

```
style="position: absolute;
        margin-left: -450px;
        left: 50%;
        top: 0;
        width: 900px;
        background-color: red"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: -150px 0 0 -150px;
    background: navy;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```